# SAX and parsing line by line with Java

Tags: java, sax

Is it possible to use SAXParser to parse xml file line by line?

Comment: What would you expect it to do when the open and close tags weren't on the same line?

Comment: I dont think there is a reason to downvote a question, it is after all a question with two logical answers yes or no.

Comment: I would like to read file line by line and to parse it with SAX and if there is some conditions met to write parsed line to new file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to pass each line to a second thread. e.g. through a PipedInputStream.

In the future you might be able to use continuations in Java 8 or 9 or ? to use the parser in the same thread.

The SAX parser should give you each complete event it can for the lines you have given it.

BTW: In the past I have written a "push" parser to do this, but I don't know of any standard SAX parse which will do this in one thread.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help your situation, buy SAX is event based meaning you can write code for when a certain tag criteria is matched by extending DefaultHandler:

```
class MySAXHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    public void startDocument() {
    System.out.println("Start document: ");
}
```

There are plenty of methods to override, take a look: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/XML/SAXeventhandler.htm

Hope this helps!